# Pausing a Timer and Resuming

Tags: java, android, andengine

Here is my timer class i use to control the intervals. Any of you guys are welcomed to use it.

The problem i am having is with my pause and resume. It pauases correctly, but when i try to use my resume() it doesnt resume the time. Any ideas why?

```
    public class Timer implements IUpdateHandler {
        // ===========================================================
        // Constants
        // ===========================================================

        // ===========================================================
        // Fields
        // ===========================================================
        private final ITimerCallback    mCallback;
        private float                                   mInterval;

        private float                                   mSecondsElapsed;
        protected boolean                               mPause  = false;

        private float                                   pausedSecond;

        // ===========================================================
        // Constructors
        // ===========================================================
        public Timer(final float interval, final ITimerCallback pCallback) {
        this.mInterval = interval;
        this.mCallback = pCallback;

        }

        // ===========================================================
        // Getter & Setter
        // ===========================================================
        public void setInterval(final float pInterval) {
        this.mInterval = pInterval;
        }

        // ===========================================================
        // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
        // ===========================================================
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

        this.mSecondsElapsed += pSecondsElapsed;
        if (this.mSecondsElapsed >= this.mInterval) {
        if (!this.mPause) {
        this.mSecondsElapsed -= this.mInterval;
        this.mCallback.onTick();
        }
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
        this.mSecondsElapsed = 0;

        }

        // ===========================================================
        // Methods
        // ===========================================================

        // ===========================================================
        // Inner and Anonymous Classes
        // ===========================================================
        public interface ITimerCallback {
                public void onTick();
        }

        public void pause() {

        this.mPause = true;
        this.pausedSecond = this.mSecondsElapsed;
        }

        public void resume() {
        if (this.mPause) {
        this.mSecondsElapsed = this.pausedSecond;
        this.mPause = false;

        } else {
        // not paused
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the TimerHandler class that is part of AndEngine? Works like a charm for me.

Comment: Well it doesnt have the methods i need.

Comment: It does have all of the methods listed in your code above. Maybe take a look: org.anddev.andengine.engine.handle.timer.TimerHandler

Answer (score 1):

What scen said

```
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

        this.mSecondsElapsed += pSecondsElapsed;
        if (this.mSecondsElapsed >= this.mInterval) {
            if (!this.mPause) {
                this.mSecondsElapsed -= this.mInterval;
            }
            this.mCallback.onTick();
        }
    }
```

That should do the trick; just move the onTick outside of the if it's not paused

Comment: If you do this, make sure everywhere you are using the .onTick() callback method, you are checking if the timer is paused and handling that appropriately.

Comment: Yet again, I agree with this Scen character ;) This will just make sure that it keeps getting called, but if you dont want your onTick to be called if it's not paused, simply check in your onTick, but make sure the update is still called

Comment: I think i am going to stick with your method above.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb here, since I can't see the code that's driving how the Timer's onUpdate function is being called, and I don't know much about the IUpdateHandler interface you are using.

It looks like you are only making a call to mCallback.onTick() if the timer isn't paused.

However, if onTick sets up the next call to the Timer's onUpdate function, then when you pause it, and it 'ticks', it won't call the onTick method and set up the next call to the function.

Comment: Good point...hmmm Any suggestions on going about correcting this?

Comment: I guess it depends. Is this timer implementation entirely yours, or is it part of the "andengine" you have tagged?

Comment: I have a timer implementation that I'm using where I let it 'tick' even if it's paused, but I keep track of how much time is remaining. IF it's paused, I don't reduce the amount. It's very similar to what you are doing.

Comment: If you do this, make sure everywhere you are using the .onTick() callback method, you are checking if the timer is paused and handling that appropriately.